I have extracted Test case Json from one ADO organization but dont know how to insert it in new organization
I have extracted Test case Json from one ADO organization but how to insert it in new organization , i have added test case and suits it's created in new org. But for test case the response i received is
used url: https://dev.azure.com/{}/{}/_apis/testplan/Plans/2362/Suites/2495/TestCase?api-version=7.1-preview.3
{
"count": 0,
"value": []
}
I need json to Post the test cases to new org

Glad to see you in Stack overflow. I can reproduce the same, it's caused by the rest api used, and not have configurations in the payjson body. Please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries.

There are two rest apis to add cases to Test Suite:

Suite Test Case - Add

Test Suites - Add


The rest api you are using is the 1st one, it's used to add test cases to a suite with specified configurations. You should specify the work item ID and configurationId in the payload json, without configurationID, it will show {"count": 0,"value": [] } as you seen. Please check the similar ticket for more details.

script sample below:
# Define variables for the new organization
$newOrganization = "orgname"
$newProject = "project"
$newPat = "PAT"
$newBase64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$newPat"))
$planId = "12436"
$suiteId = "12437"


$body = @(
    @{
        pointAssignments = @(
            @{configurationId = 3}
            @{configurationId = 38}
        )
        workItem = @{id = 12434}
    }
    @{
        pointAssignments = @(
            @{configurationId = 3}
            @{configurationId = 38}
        )
        workItem = @{id = 12435}
    }
) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5



$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $newBase64AuthInfo); "Content-Type"="application/json"} -Body $body

# Output the response
$response



The 2nd rest api doesn't reqire ConfigurationId, test case id is needed.

Sample code:
# Define variables for the new organization
$newOrganization = "org"
$newProject = "project"
$newPat = "PAT"
$newBase64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$newPat"))
$planId = "12436"
$suiteId = "12437"


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$newOrganization/$newProject/_apis/test/Plans/$planId/suites/$suiteId/testcases/12434,12435,12438?api-version=7.1-preview.3" `
                              -Method Post `
                              -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $newBase64AuthInfo); "Content-Type"="application/json-patch+json"}

# Output the response
$response


Both rest apis are used to add existing test cases(in same organization) to your test suite. It means you need to create the test cases in new organization with same content in old organization, then use the rest api above to add the test cases to Test suite.
The another way could be more simple, you can export the test cases from old organization, remove the ID column in csv file. Then import the csv file into the new test suite in new Organization.


@PraveenM, please follow above script for a check, the issue is caused by the incorrect request body.  let me know if you still have any queries, thanks.
